# How to use sqlautocode?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I've download a sqlautocode zip file from it's site. And runing:

```
python e:\sqlautocode\setup.py install
```

but when i try to:

```
import sqlautocode
```

it says 'No module named sqlautocode'.

Some blogs say:

```
sqlautocode.py xxx
```

But i can't find any file named sqlautocode.py in my system.

So, what should i do to run it?

Thanks!

Here is what i got after install sqlautocode:

```
C:\Users\Aman>python f:\sqlautocode\setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to sqlautocode.egg-info\requires.txt
writing sqlautocode.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to sqlautocode.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to sqlautocode.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to sqlautocode.egg-info\entry_points.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

reading manifest file 'sqlautocode.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'sqlautocode.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\entry_points.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying sqlautocode.egg-info\zip-safe -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
creating 'dist\sqlautocode-0.6b1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing sqlautocode-0.6b1-py2.7.egg
removing 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sqlautocode-0.6b1-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sqlautocode-0.6b1-py2.7.egg
Extracting sqlautocode-0.6b1-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
sqlautocode 0.6b1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing sqlautocode-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing sqlautocode.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sqlautocode-0.6b1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for sqlautocode==0.6b1
Searching for sqlalchemy==0.8.0b2
Best match: sqlalchemy 0.8.0b2
Processing sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py2.7.egg
sqlalchemy 0.8.0b2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for sqlautocode==0.6b1
```

Comment: Are you able to run `python sqlautocode.py --help` from the C:\Python27\Scripts directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give more info about the install? I can only give you some suggestion.

1. check the install log, whether there are some error info.
2. check the python version which you install to.
3. I recommend to use pip to install the 3rd libs, it can install the dependency automatically.

Comment: problem solved after i copy the inner sqlautocode floder into c:\python27

Comment: That's ok. But I still suggest you need to check your environment settings. From logs, it had copied the sqlautocode into site-packages. It should work. You can also get the return of `sys.path`, and revise your environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to jinghli's answer, I suspect that C:\Python27\Scripts is missing from your PATH environment variable.

Whilst moving the sqlautocode folder into C:\Python27 has resolved this particular issue, you'll encounter similar problems in the future when installing other modules.

Adding C:\Python27\Scripts to your PATH variable (remembering to log off and back in again) should be done as a matter of course, but you can test this by modifying your PATH, moving the autocode folder back to its original place and seeing if it still works.

Comment: I have installed pip as jinghli recommend. thank you all the same!